# OpenGL library not linking

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, shared-libraries

I have this error on Ubuntu Eclipse that doesn't go away:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -o "GLUT"  ./src/GLUT.o   -lglut -lGLU
/usr/bin/ld: ./src/GLUT.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glEnable'
//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched for glut:

```
# find / -name *glut.so*
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so
```

Then I went to: project properties > C/C++ Build > Settings GCC C++ Linker > Libraries :

```
// added
Libraries (-l): glut GLU
Library search path (-L): /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

The error is still the same. Any suggestion on what step should I have missed? All comments are highly welcome.

Comment: I think you also need to add GL and GLU libraries, try adding them the same way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add also GL and GLU libraries, try adding them the same way.